# Selecionar algo que contenha colchetes no nome em uma função JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Boa noite.

Estou tentando usar este código javascript para exibir o "value" de um "radio" em um formulário:

```js
document.userForm.onclick = function(){
    var radVal = document.userForm.[rads].value;
    result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
}
```

Porém em name="..." tenho colchetes, neste exemplo: name="[rads]", e o código javascript não está funcionando devido os colchetes.

O resultado do radio selecionado no formulário, será exibido neste código:

```html
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="4" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Já tentei mudar no javascript para estas formas:

```
var radVal = document.userForm.\\[rads\\].value;
var radVal = document.userForm.['[rads]'].value;
```

Mas nenhuma delas funcionou. Aqui podemos ver que o código funciona desde que não tenha os colchetes https://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Shields/23kg3tf4/1/.
O que devo alterar no código para que funcione corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estavas quase lá. Não podes misturar o *ponto* para aceder à propriedade e ao mesmo tempo os colchetes. Ou seja `objeto.[propriedade]` é sintaxe inválida. O *ponto* está a mais.

Deves usar assim:

```js
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
    var radVal = document.mainForm['[rads]'].value;
    result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="[rads]" value="4" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/97kz9ak0/

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, funcionou perfeitamente.